# Salesforce Lightning Resource and Open Source Lghtning Component

Tags: open-source

Where I can find some Lghtning Component source code for my study.

Comment: Do you mean examples of Lightning Components you can work through or the underlying source code that Salesforce uses to implement Lightning Components (a bit like [aura](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura))?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tutorials and other resources for Lightning Components with sample code:

- [Lightning Component Developer's Guide](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/lightning/lightning.pdf)
- [Lightning Components module on Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lightning_components)
- [Jeff Douglas's Build Your First Lightning Component](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2014/10/14/tutorial-build-your-first-lightning-component/)
- [Developerforce Lightning Components Tutorial](http://developerforce.github.io/lightning-components-tutorial/)
- [Lightning Components Sample App: Belgian Beer Explorer](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/02/lightning-components-sample-app-belgian-beer.html)
- [Transforming Analytics API Data for Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/transforming-analytics-api-data-salesforce1-lightning-components.html)

Keep an eye on the [Salesforce Developers' blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/) for more posts on Lightning.